# query to check if records exists in both or either of 2 columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table where i need to compare 2 column. See below example:
I need query where i should group Column 1 & 2 and tell ABC = XYZ = 123, group by date and get sum of qty.

I tried query where i used comparing (column1 = column2 or column2 = column1) & used group by date. BUt i am not getting expected result.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

**Edit:**
Added Sample data & expected result. I am expecting answer where row 1 & row 2 are same since data from column 2 match is found in column 1.

[image]

Comment: Post sample data and expected results and explain better your requirement.

Comment: Added data & expected result in question

Answer (score 0):

I try create select for your expected result, but there will be set some statements for ignore row which was changed:

```
SELECT col1, col2, done_at, SUM(qty) FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, done_at, qty, 0 AS semiline
        FROM test WHERE 1

UNION ALL

    SELECT test1.col2 AS col1, test1.col1 AS col2, test1.done_at, test1.qty, 1 AS semiline
        FROM test AS test1
        JOIN test AS test2 ON test1.col2=test2.col1
        WHERE 1 GROUP BY test1.col2, test1.col1, test1.done_at

) AS result WHERE 1
GROUP BY col1, done_at;

+------+------+------------+----------+
| col1 | col2 | done_at    | SUM(qty) |
+------+------+------------+----------+
| ABC  | XYZ  | 2017-12-29 |        2 | <-- this row is bad, i think...
| XYZ  | 123  | 2017-12-29 |        3 |
| XYZ  | 123  | 2018-10-04 |        7 |
+------+------+------------+----------+
```